# asp.net c# working with iis express but not with iis local

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am working with asp.net and c#
What I want to do is to change the label 'color' and run notepad on clicking button.
When I am testing this in visual studio (iis express) everything works perfectly but when I run it in iis local the label goes to red but notepad cannot be run. what am I doing wrong?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe");
}
```

Comment: Is there an error when trying to run the external process?  This is a strange setup, as this would clearly only produce a meaningful result (opening Notepad) when the client and server are the same machine.  When deployed to any actual server, the client would never see the application start.

Comment: there is no errors. the label goes red on iis local but notepad does not open

Comment: It's possible that the web server doesn't have permission to execute other applications by default.  (Because it generally shouldn't need to, and leaving that open would be an unnecessary security vulnerability.)  I'd expect that to produce an exception though.  Which I suppose it might be and perhaps you're simply not seeing it effectively?  Taking a step back, what is the goal here?  Using a web server to open Notepad is... very strange.  Perhaps you're going about this the wrong way in the first place, but it's hard to say for certain without knowing the intent.

Comment: hehehe, what i am trying to do is not to open notepad, it is just an example. what i am trying to do is to send udp data to arduino but i dont have one on me now so i thought that trying to run an app give me a "visual" result

Comment: ser on IIS only have GUEST privilege and cannot run any application or access the c: drive on the IIS.  If it is working on Express you must be running app As Admin

Comment: @Pat: Will that require executing a process?  If not then this isn't really a meaningful proof of concept in the first place.  I would expect to communicate with Arduino some other way, perhaps by opening a socket or a comm port to send data.

Comment: ah ok guys, thx for your answers

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you run application in IIS Express, the whole application run under your **current login user**. However, when you migrate the application to IIS, everything executed under **application pool identity**. By default app pool identity(IIS apppool\appoolname) don't have permission to access C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe.
So you can try to set app pool identity to **local system**. If it works, then you can replace the identity with your own user.